# Recursion tree with Fibonacci -Python-

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I'm learning about recursion and I wrote this (inefficient) n'th Fibonacci number calculator:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

I know that in recursion, you can draw so called 'recursion trees'. When I made this simple binary generator:

```
def binary(length, outstr=""):
    if len(outstr) == length:
        print(outstr)
    else:
        for i in ["0", "1"]:
            binary(length, outstr + i)
```

I could figure out what this tree looks like:
[image]

But I cannot figure out the tree of the Fibonacci function! What would that tree look like?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can easily visualize recursive function using [recursion-visualiser](https://github.com/sarangbishal/Recursion-Tree-Visualizer) package in Python.
Here is how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126148/7552117

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example *fibonacci(4)* gives the following recursive tree, because require two function call: *fibonacci(3)* and *fibonacci(2)*, so every call to the function, call other two functions, until you reach the exit conditions.

```
            4
           / \
          /   \
         /     \
        3       2
       / \     / \
      /   \   /   \
     2     1 1     0
    / \
   /   \
  1     0
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily visualize any  recursive function using [recursion-visualiser](https://github.com/Bishalsarang/Recursion-Tree-Visualizer) package in Python. You just need to add decorator to your function and it does the rest.

**Binary String**

Let's do it for binary string first.

```
from visualiser.visualiser import Visualiser as vs

"""
Problem Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808653/recursion-tree- 
with-fibonacci-python/60126306#60126306
"""

@vs(node_properties_kwargs={"shape":"record", "color":"#f57542","style":"filled", "fillcolor":"grey"})
def binary(length, outstr=""):
     if len(outstr) == length:
          print(outstr)
     else:
          for i in ["0", "1"]:
               binary(length=length, outstr=outstr + i)

binary(length=3,outstr="")
vs.make_animation("binary_string.gif", delay=2)
```

Here is how output animation looks like
[image: binary_string.gif]

Also the final tree is saved as :
[image: binary_string.png]

**Fibonacci:**
Let's visualise it for fib(6)

```
# Import Visualiser class from module visualiser
from visualiser.visualiser import Visualiser as vs

# Add decorator
@vs(node_properties_kwargs={"shape":"record", "color":"#f57542", "style":"filled", "fillcolor":"grey"})
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    return fib(n=n - 1) + fib(n=n-2)

def main():
    print(fib(n=6))
    vs.make_animation("fibonacci.gif", delay=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the output which looks much better:
[image: animation.gif]

Here is the final image of the recursion tree:
[image: out.png]

Check out more examples at [here](https://github.com/Bishalsarang/Recursion-Tree-Visualizer/tree/master/examples)

Comment: links are broken

Comment: Do I just need to put this anywhere on the script or in main? `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep +  'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/' `

Comment: You are required to download graphviz and add graphviz executable to PATH. You can do it manually from environment variables or alternatively add it using the above script . If you are installing from pip then the above process may not work. You may have to do it manually . Here is the link that can help you setup graphviz https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/GVIZ/pages/20971549/How+to+install+Graphviz+software

Feel free to open issue on github if any problem arises.