# Program to generate recursion tree for generic recursive program

Tags: java, c++, recursion, visualization

Often when solving a recursive or dynamic programming problem, I find myself drawing a recursion tree to help simplify the question for me. However, for some questions which are complicated I have access to the solution but no idea how to draw the tree.

What I have tried so far is printing out the calling function and it's parameters, and this has proved helpful in some examples. However, I saw this tree for fibonacci(5) here generated by mathematica in this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116344/how-do-i-create-a-recursive-tree-plot-for-the-fibonacci-sequence

[image]

I was wondering if I could generate the same kind of tree in a mainstream high level language like Python, Java, or C++? The tree could just have the nodes as the function name and parameters like in the image.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a program that generates a tree, or are you asking for an existing such a program?

Comment: @Petr If somebody had a program that generates a recursion tree that would be great, I could read the source and figure it out from there. If not, pointers on where to start would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’ve made a simple python package called [recursion-visualiser](https://github.com/Bishalsarang/Recursion-Tree-Visualizer) which you can install via pip that helps you to easily trace function calls for any arbitary recursive function and save tree as gif and png image by simply adding a decorator to your function.

Let's draw the tree for recursive Fibonacci function. 
Here is the recursive code:

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    return fib(n=n - 1) + fib(n=n - 2)

def main():
    # Call function
    print(fib(n=6))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now let's modify the code to draw recursion tree. First let's draw a very minimalist example

```
# Import Visualiser class from module visualiser
from visualiser.visualiser import Visualiser as vs

# Add decorator
@vs()
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    return fib(n=n - 1) + fib(n=n-2)

def main():
    print(fib(n=6))
    vs.make_animation("fibonacci.gif", delay=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output file is saved as *fibonacci.gif* and *fibonacci.png*.
Here is how output animation looks:
[image: Animation.gif]
Also the final image of recursion tree:
[image: tree.png]

We can also make it better using node color and other properties:

```
# Import Visualiser class from module visualiser
from visualiser.visualiser import Visualiser as vs

# Add decorator
@vs(node_properties_kwargs={"shape":"record", "color":"#f57542", "style":"filled", "fillcolor":"grey"})
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    return fib(n=n - 1) + fib(n=n-2)

def main():
    print(fib(n=6))
    vs.make_animation("fibonacci.gif", delay=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the output which looks much better:
[image: animation.gif]

Here is the final image of the recursion tree:
[image: out.png]

Check out more examples at [here](https://github.com/Bishalsarang/Recursion-Tree-Visualizer/tree/master/examples)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) and the [examples of usage](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/gallery/).

Here is an example:

```
long long fib(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    std::cout << "fib" << n << " -> fib" << n-2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "fib" << n << " -> fib" << n-1 << '\n';
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "digraph {\n";
    fib(5);
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

Running

```
program > t.dot 
dot -Tpng t.dot
```

produced:

[image]

This is more compact than the requested image, where repeated calls with the same value are represented by one node, and N edges between nodes u,v if there are N calls from fib(u) to fib(v).

To get a tree one has to maintain unique IDs for each call. Here is an example for that:

```
static unsigned id = 0;
long long fib(int n)
{
    auto call_id = id++;
    std::cout << "fib" << call_id << " [label=\"fib(" << n << ")\"]\n";
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    std::cout << "fib" << call_id << " -> fib" << id << '\n';
    auto fib_n_minus_2 = fib(n-2);
    std::cout << "fib" << call_id << " -> fib" << id << '\n';
    auto fib_n_minus_1 = fib(n-1);
    return fib_n_minus_2 + fib_n_minus_1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "digraph {\n";
    fib(5);
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

And the graph is:
[image]